# Add multiple products with diferent quantities to cart at once

Tags: 8, commerce

I would like to show a list of products along with a quantity field for each product and a single add to cart button at the bottom.

I found a module that would achieve exactly what I want in Drupal 7 https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_add_to_cart_extras and the image included represents what I would like to achieve.

Any direction / help in how you would achieve this in Drupal 8?

[image]

Comment: Not much info here but I assume you would submit the form, and in the submit handler, loop each row and if the qty is > 0, add to the cart. Although, its not that simple, because you need to either account for the delta change in items already in cart, or, wipe the entire cart and add-in from the form, without removing items _not_ in that form that are in the cart.

Comment: I was hoping it might be possible to achieve via views but no luck at the moment. 

I have created a view which lists products, showing fields. Add a relationship to Product Variations allows me to add pricing field. 

Not sure how to add quantity form field per product and a single add to cart button.

Comment: Having handled this in the past, all I remember was it's not as easy as it looks on the surface. I would advise diagramming the workflow, objects and states to help come to a solution or at least know the full scope of what you're looking at.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I am finding out it isn't as easy as I initially thought either.